# getting data from a yui datatable

Tags: javascript, yui, yui2

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjfu6/6/) that generates a `YUI Datatable` with checkboxes, but i have a problem getting the data of ids from the table after i click the `Get Records` button.

anyway to call the table from the javascript?

P.S : I am using YUI2 library as my project is using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Checkbox Listeners**

I hope this codes show what you need http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-chkboxselect.html

**Edit:**

I update your code for adding `checkboxClickEvent` for handling checkbox event in each of data row and use an array to keep all of the checked record id.

```
var selectedID = [];
```

---

```
myDataTable.subscribe("checkboxClickEvent", function(oArgs){ 
                alert("check box clicked");
                var elCheckbox = oArgs.target; 
                var oRecord = this.getRecord(elCheckbox); 
                if (elCheckbox.checked) {
                    selectedID.push(oRecord.getData("id"));
                } 
                else {
                    selectedID.pop(oRecord.getData("id"));
                }
                oRecord.setData("check",elCheckbox.checked); 
            });
```

Detail of working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjfu6/19/).

Comment: this is somewhat similar but i have difficulties trying to relate my `YUI datatable` to the button, as i only need to show the table if there are results thus the need for the `innerHTML` portion to replace with the `YUI datatable`

Comment: nvm it seems that i can just declare a var at the top of the page but it seems so untidy..

Comment: it seems that the `checkboxClickEvent` is giving me problems, is there any code for the `checkboxClickEvent` that can be used to correctly select the row that the checkbox is in?

Comment: I update your code that it only use YUI button and array to keep checked id. Please check my code. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much. i think this way its easier than for me. Its weird that my code somehow was broken when i post it the `checkboxClickEvent` was not working